# How to show images selected in gallary. Which we have already pick from gallary in ios programming?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6

I am using `ELCImagePickerController` (https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController) to pick multiple images in my code. But now I,m having problem with showing images selected in gallery when i reopen the gallery (like in whatsapp ).

Comment: Your   have paste code here, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I m trying to set imges selected in gallary which i have picked from gallary so that when i will reopen the gallary i can see my selected images as heilighted...